# SQLite syntax error (Conversion from PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax, sqlite

I am trying to merge some contents from `table1` and `table2` into another `table3`. I have the following query up and running in `PostgreSQL`:

```
CREATE TABLE table3 AS SELECT 
table1.orig_zon AS orig_zon,
table1.dest_zon AS dest_zon,
table1.same_zon AS same_zon,
table1.adjacent AS adjacent,
table1.distance AS distance,
table1.da_ivtt AS da_ivtt1,
table1.da_ovtt AS da_ovtt1,
table1.tr_avail AS tr_avail1,
table1.tr_ivtt AS tr_ivtt1,
table1.tr_ovtt AS tr_ovtt1,
table1.tr_cost AS tr_cost1,
table1.au_cost AS au_cost1,
table1.sr_ivtt AS sr_ivtt1,
table1.sr_cost AS sr_cost1,
table2.da_ivtt AS da_ivtt2,
table2.da_ovtt AS da_ovtt2,
table2.tr_avail AS tr_avail2,
table2.tr_ivtt AS tr_ivtt2,
table2.tr_ovtt AS tr_ovtt2,
table2.tr_cost AS tr_cost2,
table2.au_cost AS au_cost2,
table2.sr_ivtt AS sr_ivtt2,
table2.sr_cost AS sr_cost2,
FROM table1, table2
WHERE ((table1.orig_zon = table2.orig_zon)) AND ((table1.dest_zon = table2.dest_zon));
```

I have tested the query for a very small dummy dataset and the result is as desired. However my actual database is in `SQLite` and when I run this in the sqlite3 via Linux shell I get an error as:

```
Error: near "table1": syntax error
```

Can anyone point me to the modifications I need to make in order to make this work in SQLite? Thanks for the help!

**Edit1**:
After removing the trailing comma (see Craig's comment below) the issue persists.

**Edit2**:
After playing around a bit I found the fix. Seems very silly but if I were to pass the contents of the query in a single line the statement works!

```
table2.sr_ivtt AS sr_ivtt2,
table2.sr_cost AS sr_cost2 FROM table1, table2 WHERE ((table1.orig_zon = table2.orig_zon)) AND ((table1.dest_zon = table2.dest_zon));
```

Oh! The bane of typecasting!!

Comment: SQLite's console is newline-terminated, so edit2 makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL doesn't permit a trailing comma in the `SELECT` list.

```
table2.sr_cost AS sr_cost2,
FROM table1, table2
```

should be:

```
table2.sr_cost AS sr_cost2
FROM table1, table2
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that! But even after I change it the issue persists! Same error... Any idea why?

Comment: @RazorXsr Nope. Try progressively simplifying the query until it works, then figure out what the last part you took out was.

Comment: Your fix worked... It was just that I had to change the typing a bit... See Edit 2 above... Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete extra comma

```
table2.sr_ivtt AS sr_ivtt2,
table2.sr_cost AS sr_cost2
FROM table1, table2
```